# Keeping the text into the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am writing a web-page using bootstrap. How could I keep the text aligned on a single line? It looks fine on a large screen but for a mobile screen, it breaks into three.

I know that I have fixed the font-size of the text, but initially I want the size to be larger than it would be. Is there a fix to it? How could I keep the text aligned to a single line (as looks on PC) for a mobile screen?

Following is the `text-grid`:

```
<div class='row first-layer'>
  <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1'>  </div>      
  <div class='col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 text-center page-header'><b>Title of Web Page</b></div>
  <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1'>  </div>
</div>

.page-header {
  font-family: Calli;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #996699;
 }
```

*As displayed on PC*:

[image]

*As displayed on mobile:*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: @ThePragmatick I also want the font size to decrease as the size of viewport decreases.

Comment: Use `vw` units for `font-size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;`, but that will cause text overflow.
Its better if you set font size in `vw` units:

```css
.page-header {
  font-family: Calli;
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: #996699;
 }
```

```html
<div class='row first-layer'>
  <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1'>  </div>      
  <div class='col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 text-center page-header'><b>Title of Web Page</b></div>
  <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1'>  </div>
</div>
```